# Como retornar ao mesmo local da página após clicar no botão voltar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Estou desenvolvendo um portal, nele existem diversas notícias, quando clico em uma delas sou remetido a uma página nova que trata este assunto na íntegra, a minha dúvida é a seguinte, eu gostaria que após eu clicar no botão voltar eu retornasse para a página anterior no mesmo ponto onde eu estava lendo, ou seja, no mesmo ponto da notícia onde cliquei, alguém pode me ajudar a solucionar esta questão de navegação? Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer com [**history.go**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_go.asp):

```
javascript:history.go(-1);
```

Comment: Acho que o que ele quer é voltar no mesmo local onde o scroll estava.

Comment: @Marconi, testei aqui no Chrome e o history.go(-1) está retornando para o mesmo local no Scroll. Está retornando diferente em algum outro browser?

Comment: Obrigado Allan, vou testar.

Comment: Deu certo a resposta?